# Query para pegar informações de uma chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, query

Eu possuo uma tabela que faz relacionamento entre duas chaves estrangeiras

[image: TABELA DE RELACIONAMENTO]

Gostaria de fazer uma query onde iria fazer uma verificação do `fk_user_1` e pegar as informações do `fk_user_2`

Fiz essa **QUERY**:

`SELECT users.username, users.name, users.user_id FROM friendship AS f INNER JOIN users WHERE f.fk_user_1 = 1`

Porém esta retorna dados **duplicados** de **USER** e traz também o **USER** de *chave estrangeira* 1, que foi o que foi feito a comparação `fk_user_1 = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Conseguir pegar somente as informações do `fk_user_2` **sem** estar **duplicado** os dados com essa **QUERY**:

`SELECT users.username, users.name, users.user_id FROM friendship AS f INNER JOIN users WHERE fk_user_1 = 1 AND f.fk_user_2 = user_id`